# Not able to execute Merge query on Bigquery table which contains numeric column

Tags: google-bigquery, upsert

I want to execute MERGE query in BigQuery tables which contain numeric column.When I used below query to execute I am getting error as Query error: `Value of type FLOAT64 cannot be assigned to Numeric`, which has type NUMERIC.

In my case, Its not possible to recognize datatype of number fields otherwise I can cast as per datatype of column.

Query =

```
MERGE Target T USING
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT 874 as ID,1012.0 as numericVal) S ON T.numericVal= S .numericVal WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ID= S .ID,numericVal = S .numericVal 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ROW;
```

Comment: Cast them as STRING and load into you destination columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to change the source, try casting as numeric and it'll be rounded accordingly

`SELECT 874 as ID, CAST(1012.0 as NUMERIC) as numericVal`